# Get json object created in mvc (jsonResult) in android

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc, json

I created a json result in mvc and I'm building an Android app to get the json result. This is what my json result looks like

```
{"name":"Mr. Spock","gender":"Male"}
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var result = new { name = "Mr. Spock", gender = "Male" };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

And this I'm using in android

```
// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

JSONParser class

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

I have a declared variable url. Every time I debug, the json variable does not have any values and says "errors during the evaluation"

Anyone with a tip? I tried working with Gson, but no succes

Kind regards

Comment: That horrible `JSONParser` class is an example of how a bad tutorial can propagate crappy code all over the internet. Question - what problem did you run into using Gson to process your data?

Comment: Doubly agree on Gson. Makes for much more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some code for Gson. It really is much easier to work with than the built in JSON parsing code. Here's a minimal example using your JSON.

Person.class:

```
package com.example.tutorial.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Person {

    @SerializedName("gender")
    public String gender = "";

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name = "";
}
```

The annotations are really only necessary when your variable and JSON name differ, but I tend to always include them as it reinforces that they are coming from JSON.

To deserialize:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Person person = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

It really is that simple. If this does not work, log the result from the web server and make sure it really is the valid JSON string you expect it to be.

I do have one question, where is your AsyncTask? Your attempt to open a connection to the webserver in the UI thread will definitely cause a NetworkOnMainThreadException. I created a library to do RESTful calls on Android. It's licensed under BSD, so feel free to use it as a guide or outright use it: https://github.com/nedwidek/Android-Rest-API